# tableview reload data method being called, but not executing

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a tableview in my app, it must display a list of chat messages. I got the chat messages loaded into a `NSMutableArray` and after loading the data into the array, I need to update the tableview.

here is the code I am using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    ("reloading data")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

But it prints out `reloading data` but does not update / reload the tableview.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I have realized that it is not calling this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    println("running")
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
    println(listDataArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.textLabel?.text = (listDataArray[indexPath.row] as NSString)
    return cell
}
```

but if I try and remove it, or comment it out, it them says the class does not conform to the protocols of the `UITableViewDataSource`.

So then how can it just not call the method? `(NOTE: it is not printing "running" either)`

**UPDATE 2**

here is the code for the `tableview` methods (note I have changed the one slightly from when I posted above)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(listDataArray.count > 0) {
        return listDataArray.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if !(cell != nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = listDataArray[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your array isn't being updated as you think or perhaps your cellForRowAtIndexPath is wrong... It could be a number of things...

Comment: I know the array is being updated because if I print it out, the new content is there

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: @adnan No, this is Swift.

Comment: @JoshHarington Could you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method? Are you reusing cells?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have updated the question. The method seems to not being called at all?

Comment: 1. Did you set the table view's delegate? 2. If "the class does not conform to the protocols of the UITableViewDataSource" it means you haven't implemented all the required methods. Did you also implement `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: @LyndseyScott yes I did

Comment: Could you post all your table view methods?

Comment: And your class header looks something like this, right? `class ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: @LyndseyScott yes it does

Comment: Is your table's `datasource` property set to your class?

Comment: I think those `tableView` funcs should be marked as `override`.

Comment: You do this self.tableView.reloadData() right after the array is updated.  In the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question, but don't you forget to set `dataSource` property?

Comment: I deleted the datasource property, cleaned the project and then set it again. Seems to work but I don't know why?

Comment: it is possible that Xcode used old version of compiled code, which did not include datasource setup. That is why cleaning helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift , than you should not use NSMutableArray. Try and look at the methods swift provides and use that.

For example listDataArray should be initialized as

```
 var listDataArray = ["TYPE OF OBJECT"] ()
```